# ggplot how to plot pie charts on USA map with state's id

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I would like to plot pie charts of different fuel type for each state on USA map.
my data includes fuel types and their amount and each state id. I want to know how to plot pie on map for each state with state id?

Thanks,

```
data <- data.frame(region= c(AL, AR, AZ, CA, IA), 
                  gas= c(25, 45, 45, 60, 75),
                  coal= c(45, 50, 45, 20, 15), 
                  wind= c(30, 5, 10, 20, 10), 
                  solar= c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
```

Comment: Do not forget to use quotes `region = c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "IA")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** The `usmap` has been modernized in version [`0.7.0`](https://github.com/cran/usmap/blob/master/NEWS.md#usmap-070) and now returns data as simple features. Hence, getting the coordinates for the scatter pies requires slightly more effort to retrieve the coordinates from the sf object:

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

states <- us_map("states")

centroids <- usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")

centroids <- cbind(
  abbr = centroids$abbr,
  sf::st_coordinates(centroids)
) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  transform(
    X = as.numeric(X),
    Y = as.numeric(Y)
  )

data_merged <- merge(
  data, centroids,
  by.x = "region", by.y = "abbr",
  all.x = TRUE
)

plot_usmap(regions = "states") +
  geom_scatterpie(
    aes(x = X, y = Y),
    data = data_merged, cols = c("gas", "coal", "wind", "solar")
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(X, Y, label = region),
    data = data_merged, vjust = 1, nudge_y = -100000
  )
```

[image]

**Original answer**

Using the `usmap` and the `scatterpie` packages this could be achieved via `ggplot2` like so:

1. Add coordinates for the pies to your data. In the code below I use the coordinates of the state centers provided by `usmapdata::centroid_labels`
2. Add the pies from your data via `geom_scatterpie`

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

states <- us_map("states")

centroids <- usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")[c("x", "y", "abbr")]

data <- merge(data, centroids, by.x = "region", by.y = "abbr", all.x = TRUE)

plot_usmap(regions = "states") +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x, y, group = region),
    data = data, cols = c("gas", "coal", "wind", "solar")
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = region),
            data = data, vjust = 1, nudge_y = -100000
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** If you want to exclude some states (or include only some states) you could do so via the `exclude` or `include` argument of  `plot_usmap`:

```r
plot_usmap(regions = "states", exclude = c("AK", "HI")) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x, y, group = region),
                  data = data, cols = c("gas", "coal", "wind", "solar")
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = region),
            data = data, vjust = 1, nudge_y = -100000
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(
  region = c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "IA"),
  gas = c(25, 45, 45, 60, 75),
  coal = c(45, 50, 45, 20, 15),
  wind = c(30, 5, 10, 20, 10),
  solar = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Stefan. It worked! Now I want to only have US 49 states (not including Alaska and Hawaii). Is there a way in usmap package to have only us 49 states? (for example in Rmap this will do it:  rmap::map(mapUS49)). I searched it for us map package and couldn't find such option.

Comment: Hi @Arwen. Sure is this possible. See my edit.