# In R use plot_usmap with color and geom_scatterpie together

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, usmap, scatterpie

I want to make a map that has color for each state represent an variable. At same time, I want to add a pie chart for each state while keep the color in the last step.

So far, I can make the colored map with plot_usmap

[image]

and pie chart on map use geom_scatterpie separately

[image]

I wonder if I can combine them together as one map.

I tried to combine those two function with '+', but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried and some reproducible code using `dput`?

Answer (score 2):

Sure is this possible. But you have to be aware that by default we can only have one `fill` scale so you have to keep an eye on the type of values (continuous vs. discrete) mapped on the `fill` aesthetic for the `plot_usmap` and `geom_scatterpie` part. One option to circumvent that would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales for the same aesthetic as I do in my example below.

Using some fake example data based on my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504314/ggplot-how-to-plot-pie-charts-on-usa-map-with-states-id/72505513#72505513) and the default example from `plot_usmap`.

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)
library(ggnewscale)

data <- data.frame(region= c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "IA"), 
                   gas= c(25, 45, 45, 60, 75),
                   coal= c(45, 50, 45, 20, 15), 
                   wind= c(30, 5, 10, 20, 10), 
                   solar= c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10))

states <- us_map("states")

centroids <- usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")[c("x", "y", "abbr")]

data <- merge(data, centroids, by.x = "region", by.y = "abbr", all.x = TRUE)

plot_usmap(data = statepop, values = "pop_2015") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "BuGn") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x, y, group = region),
                  data = data, cols = c("gas", "coal", "wind", "solar")
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = region),
            data = data, vjust = 1, nudge_y = -100000
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "left")
```

[image]